# How can i print json file that is produced from ParseHub on screen?

Tags: php, json, parsehub

I use ParseHub to get data from an Ajax-based website. The data is returned in json file format. I have been struggling to print returned json file for hours, but could not be successful. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

$params = http_build_query(array(
"api_key" => "xxxxx",
"format" => "json"
));

$result = file_get_contents(
'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/{MY_RUN_TOKEN}/last_ready_run/data?'.$params,
false,
stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET'
    )
))
);

echo $result;


?>
```

By the way, json_decode() function didn't work. Can anyone help me?

UPDATE: I uploaded code and output of the code. You can check to give some ideas.

Code -> this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue2Ye.jpg)
Output -> this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybjh.jpg)

Comment: You probably already checked this, but the URL is correct and $result is a string?  (not a bool)

Comment: Can you give full code?With json_decode() function

Comment: Also can you give dumped $result variable?

Comment: @billrichards i added gzdecode($result) function and now i can print it as a string. But i need to take it as a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ParseHub API documentation](https://www.parsehub.com/docs/ref/api/v2/?plaintext#get-data-for-a-run):

> The Content-Encoding of this response is always gzip.

Try to use [gzdecode](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.gzdecode.php) function for your $result variable. And then decode it with json_decode().

Note that it requires PHP 5 >= 5.4.0 or PHP 7 version.
Also you can try to use [Parsehub REST api wrapper class](https://github.com/msankhala/parsehub-php).

Comment: Yes gzdecode works. Thanks for your help. I added this line after getting $result :

    $data=gzdecode($result);
    echo $data;

But gzdecode returns string. So $data is not a json. Now, the problem is converting string $data into json. :)

Comment: When i try to use: 
    echo json_decode($data); it throws that error: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\a.php on line 20"

Comment: I uploaded final code and output of the code. Can you check and give some idea please?
Code -> this [link](https://imgur.com/egarydf)
Output -> this [link](https://imgur.com/93DgSn2)

Comment: Actually, when i run the php code on the postman application and check result in json mode, i can see it in json format. I am not sure but the problem is looks like solved. Here is what i see: [link](https://imgur.com/ZImkd9Y)

Comment: Yes, this is JSON data. Use `json_decode($data, true);` to decode it.

Comment: gzdecode() is solved my problem without using json_decode($data,true) function. If json_decode function is used, it return error that says "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\a.php on line 20". But without json_decode, it is okay. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Btw, var_dump($result) is string, it is not json.

Comment: If you want, you can ask their support about it. [Here](https://www.parsehub.com/docs/ref/api/v2/?plaintext#get-last-ready-data) they wrote that `format` can be `csv` or `json`.

Comment: I have wrote already. But they said "use gzdecode()". Not much more than.